# ant - how to comment all lines except those matching a specific string

Tags: string, ant, replace, matching

I would like to comment all lines of a SQL script except those containing the string TABLE1 (case sensitive) and - if possible - using only a single ant task (replaceregexp?).
Ideally, the comment (starting with "--") and blank lines should be ignored but if not this is not so important.

Ex:
Initial file

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (TEST_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, TEST_NAME VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE LICENSE (ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, PRIMARY KEY (ID));

delete from TEST2 where
    ID = 'whatever'
;

delete from TEST3 where
    ENV = 'whatelse'
;

UPDATE TEST1 SET VERSION = '1.0';
```

Final file

```
-- CREATE TABLE TEST (TEST_ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, TEST_NAME VARCHAR(255));
-- CREATE TABLE LICENSE (ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, PRIMARY KEY (ID));

-- delete from TEST2 where
--  ID = 'whatever'
-- ;

-- delete from TEST3 where
--  ENV = 'whatelse'
-- ;

UPDATE TEST1 SET VERSION = '1.0';
```

The only solutions I have found are those ones:
1. Comment out all lines of the script and then uncomment the lines that matches the string TEST1:

```
    <replaceregexp file="${sql.file}"
        match="(.*)"
        replace="-- \1"
        byline="true"
    />
    <replaceregexp file="${sql.file}"
        match="^-- (.*TEST1)"
        replace="\1"
        byline="true"
    />
```

1. Create a new file that only contains the line I want to keep:

   ```
   <copy file="${sql.file}" tofile="${sql.file.bak}">
     <filterchain>
       <linecontains>
         <contains value="TEST1"/>
       </linecontains>
     </filterchain>
   </copy>
   ```

I am not so happy with both solutions as:
 Solution #1. uses 2 tasks and updates the same file twice
 Solution #2. removes the other lines we would like to keep as comment

If anybody has the right answer I take it.

Thanks,
Sabrina

Comment: Why ANT? It's a very poor scripting environment.

Comment: Ant because I've got no choice, I am asked to maintain someone's else code which is written in ant. What language do you think is the best for that?

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be

```
<replaceregexp file="${sql.file}"
     match="(^(?!$))(?!.*TEST1)"
     replace="-- \1"
     byline="true" />
```

The key to this is that `?!` is the "negative look-ahead assertion" - it says a match is found when the string in brackets after the `?!` is *not* found.

Here's an [explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%5E%28?!%24%29%29%28?!.%2aTEST1%29) of the pattern:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                               the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TEST1                    'TEST1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: What great, it works like a charm, many thanks! I would have few questions though: what does (^(?!$)) mean, ^ is for the beginning of the line and $ the end? I do not fully understand (though I guess) why ?!$. Your explanation will be most welcome.

Comment: Ok, I understood: ^(?!$) match non-empty lines.

Comment: A further optimization is possible: Since \1 always expands to empty in this case, you can omit it:
<replaceregexp file="${sql.file}"
     **match="^(?!$)(?!.*TEST1)"**
     **replace="-- "**
     byline="true" />

Comment: The answer that best meets the requirements seems to be: <replaceregexp file="${sql.file2}"
      match="^(?!($|--))(?!.*TEST1)"
      replace="-- "
      byline="true"
/>